# Нужна ли запятая, если первая часть однородного подчинения осложнена придаточным?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

**Требование удовлетворено, поскольку факт просрочки установлен актами, а выданные листы не исполнены, и поскольку факт непринятия основанием освобождения не является.**

Answer (score 3):

Долго читала, чтобы понять смысл, что именно соединяют союзы И и А. Верно ли поняла:*Требование касается наказания за неисполнение*.  *Требование удовлетворено, поскольку факт просрочки установлен актами и поскольку факт непринятия решения основанием для освобождения от исполнения  не является*? Если верно, то тогда нужно перестроить громоздкую конструкцию, чтобы прояснить смысл:

1 вар.*Требование удовлетворено, поскольку выданные листы не исполнены и факт просрочки установлен актами, а факт непринятия решения основанием для освобождения от исполнения не является*.

2 вар. *Требование удовлетворено, поскольку выданные листы не исполнены,  факт просрочки установлен актами, а  непринятие решения основанием для освобождения от исполнения не является*.

3 вар.*Требование удовлетворено, поскольку  факт просрочки установлен актами (выданные листы не исполнены), а факт непринятия решения основанием для освобождения от исполнения не является*.

4 вар. *Требование удовлетворено, поскольку выданные листы не исполнены, факт просрочки установлен актами и  непринятие решения основанием для освобождения от исполнения не является*.

В первоначальном виде запятая перед И не нужна, она не повторяется, но вопросов к логике предложения много.

Comment: На самом деле предложение ещё более громоздкое, я сократила детали, оставив грамматические основы. Вопрос в принципе, нужна ли запятая, если есть ещё придаточное, относящееся к первой части

Comment: Нет, не нужна, это однородное подчинение, повторяющихся союзов  там нет. Но и союз А здесь неуместен, лучше бы смотрелся И, а тогда и союз был бы повторяющимся, и запятая была бы на месте.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Требование удовлетворено, поскольку (2) факт просрочки установлен актами, а (3)  выданные листы не исполнены, и (4) поскольку факт непринятия основанием освобождения не является.**

Я понимаю конструкцию так: требование удовлетворено по ряду причин, изложенных **в трех придаточных предложениях.** Все они соподчинены главному предложению (1), и **союз ПОСКОЛЬКУ относится ко всем придаточным**, просто повторяется он только два раза.

Между придаточными союзная связь: союз А между придаточными (2) и (3), затем  союз И перед придаточным (4).

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что запятая перед И не нужна: **Здесь имеет место сочинительная связь трех однородных придаточных, обозначенная разными союзами.**

Comment: А если по смыслу 3 относится к 2, а не к 1? Предложение сильно сокращено, я оставила только грамматические основы

Comment: А если по смыслу 3 относится к 2, а не к 1? Предложение сильно сокращено, я оставила только грамматические основы

Comment: В приведенной конструкции предложение (1) называет действие, ТРИ других (придаточных) предложения объясняют причины этого действия. (3) связано с (2) сочинительной противительной связью, но ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ связь у всех предложений ОДИНАКОВАЯ: все они относятся к (1), в том числе и (3).  Вспомним правило, когда запятая не ставится. Это должны быть ДВА однородных придаточных, которые связаны одиночным союзом И и которые располагаются после главного предложения. (В этом случае они образуют единую фразу и читаются без паузы, поэтому и нет запятой).

Comment: Согласна, но все же напишу полный текст: Требование удовлетворено, поскольку факт просрочки погашения долга установлен судебными актами, а выданные на их основании исполнительные листы заказчиком не исполнены, и поскольку тот факт... и т.д. Если считать, что придаточное "а выданные..." не является одним из трёх однородных, а уточняет второе?

Comment: Предложения 2 и 3 связаны сочинительной связью, союз А имеет значение сопоставления, поэтому 3 не может уточнять 2, между ними сопоставительные смысловые отношения. Таким образом, это три однородных придаточных причины, но между собой они дополнительно связаны разными сочинительными союзами. И уж в любом случае перед союзом И должна ставиться запятая.

Comment: Лучше бы Вы написали без сокращений, как есть, хоть смысл был бы понятен.