# Знаки препинания в СПП при наличии сочинительных союзов между придаточными

Tags: пунктуация

Дано предложение: **Он подумал, что скоро ехать, а вещи еще не собраны, и что надо бы поторопиться.**

Какова грамматическая структура предложения и нужна ли запятая перед союзом И?

Предложение составлено по образцу другого предложения из вопроса [Нужна ли запятая, если первая часть однородного подчинения осложнена придаточным?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444211/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)

Answer (score 2):

Если однородные придаточные части соединены разными одиночными сочинительными союзами, запятые между ними не ставятся.
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=376#pg376

*Он подумал, (что /скоро ехать, а вещи еще не собраны/) и (что надо бы поторопиться).*

Только структура этого предложения не повторяет структуру предложения из указанного вопроса, здесь логика построения предложения соблюдена, хотя структура и необычна: ...что скоро ехать, а вещи не собраны...- это и соподчинённые придаточные, и в то же время они соединены между собой сочинительной противительной связью, такой вот "дуплексив".

В том предложении нарушена логика построения противительной связи: **просрочка зафиксирована в документах, а лист не исполнен**. В чём противоречие? А если б не была зафиксирована, то лист был бы исполнен? Как неисполнение влияет на фиксацию? Логично поменять местами: лист не исполнен, а эта просрочка зафиксирована.Сначала лист не исполнен, а потом это неисполнение, просрочку, зафиксировали. так что всё равно здесь грамматическая ошибка построения предложения.

Comment: У Розенталя речь идет о союзах И, ИЛИ "Очень раздумывать, однако, о том, что двоилось у меня в глазах или на самом деле след был двойной и как могло быть, что от одной птицы шел двойной след... (Пришв.) — три придаточные части изъяснительные, соединенные союзами или и и".  Это совсем ДРУГОЙ вариант, противительный союз А к этому пункту никаким образом НЕ ОТНОСИТСЯ  Два придаточных соединены союзом ИЛИ, потом эта группа соединяется союзом И с третьим придаточным. Для союза А этот "номер" не пройдет, это же очевидно.

Comment: Это понятно, но других правил на этот счёт нет, потому что противительные союзы между однородными придаточными не употребляются, если только как синоним И. Неоднозначная конструкция - самостоятельное решение, следуя логике мысли, иначе никак.

Comment: Если нет правил, то и ответа нет,  надо честно сказать об этом: мы не знаем, решить задачу не можем. А конструкция самая ОБЫЧНАЯ, я таких много придумать могу.  Например: Мы выйдем рано, когда солнце уже встанет, а роса еще не высохнет, и когда трава будет еще мокрой. А вот подобный пример с однородными членами: Он слушает, а не понимает, и повторить сказанное не может.

Comment: Ну, не самая обычная, а разговорная, и запятой здесь тоже нет: Мы выйдем рано, когда солнце уже встанет, а роса еще не высохнет, и когда трава будет еще мокрой. Запятая обусловлена только уточняющим характером придаточного (рано, когда именно), это "рано" будет общим и для солнца, и для росы. Он (слушает, а не понимает) и повторить сказанное не может. Запятой нет, потому что повторяющихся союзов нет, первые 2 сказуемых воспринимаются отдельной группой, они противопоставлены друг другу и присоединены к третьему.

Comment: "Рано" можно убрать, если наречие Вам мешает, вот и уточнения не будет, а ничего разговорного в таком синтаксисе я не вижу.  Всё остальное (запятые, их отсутствие и толкования на эту тему) - это Ваш выбор, меня же интересует объективное решение. Если оно никем и никогда не зафиксировано в правилах (это касается и однородных членов, и однородных придаточных), то желательно увидеть  практические примеры из классических произведений. Иначе это только Ваше личное мнение. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Правило я вам указала, только Вы почему-то его не принимаете: "Если однородные придаточные части соединены разными одиночными сочинительными союзами, запятые между ними не ставятся" В примерах нет противительных союзов, потому что разная связь между однородными членами - это уже разговорная конструкция, но Вы этого принять не хотите, дело хозяйское... Прекрасно знала, что этим закончится наша беседа - зачем отвечала? сама не знаю...